# Error mvn tomcat:run but can execute in eclipse tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, java-7

I have a Maven project with different modules like this:

- MyProject

  - testlib
  - common
  - client
  - commonserver
  - webserver

I can execute webserver inside Eclipse's tomcat without problem, I can compile it with Maven without problems but when I try to `mvn tomcat:run` webserver module, it complains it does not find a class defined in common:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myproject/core/MyException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:962)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
```

I have dependencies set in the pom (and it compiles so I don't know what's going on).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was running from parent folder like this

```
mvn -pl webserver tomcat:run
```

If I do

```
cd webserver
mvn tomcat:run
```

then it works